# R dplyr avoid `separate` from dropping the original column

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the code and data below, how can I avoid the `separate` function from dropping the original column (`GEOID`)?

Code + data (`df`):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df = structure(list(GEO_ID = c("1500000US120110101021", "1500000US120110101022", 
"1500000US120110101031", "1500000US120110101032", "1500000US120110101033", 
"1500000US120110101041"), GEO_ID_REV = c(1.2e+11, 1.2e+11, 1.2e+11, 
1.2e+11, 1.2e+11, 1.2e+11)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# Split GEO_ID into two new columns and keep the existing column as well.
df = df %>% separate(GEO_ID, c("GeoID", "US"), "US") # Drops the existing GEO_ID column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `remove` argument which is TRUE by default

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate(GEO_ID, c("GeoID", "US"), "US", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  GEO_ID                GeoID   US             GEO_ID_REV
  <chr>                 <chr>   <chr>               <dbl>
1 1500000US120110101021 1500000 120110101021 120000000000
2 1500000US120110101022 1500000 120110101022 120000000000
3 1500000US120110101031 1500000 120110101031 120000000000
4 1500000US120110101032 1500000 120110101032 120000000000
5 1500000US120110101033 1500000 120110101033 120000000000
6 1500000US120110101041 1500000 120110101041 120000000000
```